# Transpose rows to column in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to transpose rows to column in SQL Server.

My database look like this:

[image]

And I would like to transform it to this:

[image]

I did this query but it is not doing the Job, because it takes only the max time for a given day:

```
select CoachName , max(Monday) as Monday , max(Tuesday) as Tuesday ,max(Wednesday) as Wednesday     
from 
(select CoachName,
  case when DayOftheWeek = 'Monday' then StartTime end as Monday,
   case when DayOftheWeek = 'Tuesday' then StartTime end as Tuesday,
     case when DayOftheWeek = 'Wednesday' then DayOftheWeek end as Wednesday,
       case when DayOftheWeek = 'Thursday' then DayOftheWeek end as Thursday,
         case when DayOftheWeek = 'Friday' then DayOftheWeek end as Friday,
           case when DayOftheWeek = 'Saturday' then DayOftheWeek end as Saturday
 
 
 from Tbl_Semester_PreSchedule_Classes) as T
  group by CoachName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

…

```
declare @t table(coach varchar(20), dayoftheweek varchar(20), _time time);

insert into @t(coach, dayoftheweek, _time)
values
('a','Monday', '15:00'), ('a','Monday', '16:00'),
('b', 'Monday', '14:30'), ('b','Tuesday', '14:30'),
('b', 'Tuesday', '10:00');


select coach, Monday, Tuesday --*
from
(
select coach, dayoftheweek, _time, dense_rank() over(order by _time) as timeordinal
from @t
) as t
pivot
(
max(_time) for dayoftheweek in (Monday,Tuesday)
) as pv
order by coach, coalesce(Monday, Tuesday);
```

Comment: Should partition by coach, and by day, as per the existing answer.  As written, the second coach's input rows are Not collapsed to a single output row.

Comment: …@MatBailie .. no need to partition by..it is done indirectly by the pivoted columns… a unique ordinal per time makes the same time (for different days) appear in the **same row** , for a coach… which cannot happen when partitioning by coach&day

Comment: I know which one I think is right...  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=10a4355ebab44ad45ab47945ebabd54f

Comment: Even worse, if a day has two timestamps that are the same... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a2d42c86654b914ee9cba36df3977fb6

Comment: …@MatBailie … that’s intentional

Comment: That it should be explicitly stated in your answer. The question was about transposition of data, not deduplication.

Comment: @lptr, thank you for your answer, and sorry for the delay, your SQL works fine, I have a new challenge, to transpose row to column when the when the number of column is unknown. But I will post my pb in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

A simple PIVOT in concert with the window function `row_number()` should do the trick.   (Untested as you did not provide sample data as formatted text)

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select Coach
              ,DayOftheWeek
              ,Time
              ,RN = row_number() over (partition by Coach,DayOftheWeek order by [Time])
         From  Tbl_Semester_PreSchedule_Classes
       ) src
 Pivot ( max([Time]) for DayOftheWeek in ( [Monday]
                                          ,[Tuesday]
                                          ,[Wednesday]
                                          ,[Thursday]
                                          ,[Friday]
                                          ,[Saturday]
                                          ,[Sunday]
                                         ) ) pvt
```